# Sending an e-mail via VBA with Outlook Exchange

Tags: ms-access, vba, exchange-server, cdo.message

So for many years I've been using CDO to send e-mails via POP and have had no issues.  However, we are going to be upgrading to an Outlook Exchange e-mail server and POP is no longer available, it also requires TLS which I've read isn't supported by CDO.

This is what I have been doing:

```
  Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
  With cdoConfig.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "my smtpserver"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "email@email.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Update
  End With
  Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  Set objEmail.Configuration = cdoConfig
```

This has always worked in the past.  I tried updating the smtp server to  smtp.office365.com and the port to 587 but I get the following error:

```
The server rejected the sender address.  The server response was: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [MWHPR08CA0030.namprd08.prod.outlook.com]
```

I'm currently using Access 2003, we will be upgrading to 2015 soon, but for now I need a solution that works in 2003.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try sending with `smtpusessl") = True`

Comment: I did, both true and false result in the same error message.

Comment: That error message is coming from your mail server `MWHPR08CA0030.namprd08.prod.outlook.com` not `smtp.office365.com`. Have you followed instructions for setting up Direct Send from office365.com? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#DirectSendConfig